# umbraco email form not working with gmail smtp

Tags: asp.net, razor, gmail, umbraco, contact-form

I am trying to get the Cultiv Razor contact form working, but am not having much luck. I've read that you can use GMail as an smtp relay (found some solutions here, in the documentation, and on the umbraco forums which outline how to do it) but I can't get it to work. here's what my web.config looks like (masked out the user id and password here):

```
<mailSettings>
<smtp>
<network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="xxxxxx@gmail.com" password="xxxxxx" defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" />
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

and I am using a completely stock install of cultiv contact form. Here's my macro code directly on my template:

```
<umbraco:Macro MailFrom="xxxxxxx@gmail.com" Alias="Cultiv" EnableSsl="true" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
```

I have tried it with and without the ssl setting, and have tried with and without the @gmail.com part of the address. Every time I try and test the form, it reloads the page, appends #cultivcontactform to the end of the URL, the form disappears, and the following is added to the umbracolog table:

*Error creating or sending contact mail, check if there is a mailFrom property on your document and that it has a value, or specify a MailFrom parameter on the macro call exception:*

I'm stumped on this and have been for a while. I'm using Umbraco 4.11.10

Any suggestions for further troubleshooting would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the installation of the package wasn't complete, can you please check the macro-property "MailFrom" on the "Cultiv" macro?

Even if you specify the value in the umbraco:Macro tag, the macro-property has to be saved on the Macro itself.

Or, as the error suggests, add a property on your document type with the name "mailFrom" and save it with your email address.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, sorry I'm late to reply. I have confirmed that I definitely have a MailFrom parameter on the macro, and also tried adding mailFrom to my doctype. Any thing else I might try?